# node-opencv for windows

Tags: node.js, opencv

I'm trying to install either node-opencv or opencv-node in windows7, as a node module.
node and node-gyp are accessible from the command prompt.
Python and env variables are set.
I believe openCV is installed at least to the point of having the prebuilt libraries.
But for both node-opencv and opencv-node I get the same error.

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@0.7.3
gyp info using node@0.8.9 | win32 | ia32
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed:   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import platform; print platform.python_version();
gyp ERR! stack                                   ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:540:15)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:91:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:638:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:680:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure"
"build"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\wamp\www\serv\opencv-node
gyp ERR! node -v v0.8.9
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.7.3
gyp ERR! not ok
```

the log file says pretty much the same thing, any help appreciated!

-- UPDATE, after installing python 2.7.3 i now get this error:

```
C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\opencv-node>node "C:\Program Fil
es (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\b
in\node-gyp.js" configure build
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the
 file specified.
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:540:15)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:91:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:638:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.ChildProcess.spawn.stdin (child_process.js:815:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket._destroy.destroyed (net.js:357:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (nod
e.js:244:9)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\nod
e_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\opencv-node
gyp ERR! node -v v0.8.9
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.6.8
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! opencv-node@0.2.6 install: `node-gyp configure build`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-gyp configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the opencv-node@0.2.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the opencv-node package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp configure build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls opencv-node
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "opencv-node
"
npm ERR! cwd C:\wamp\www\serv\opencv-node
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.9
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.61
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\wamp\www\serv\opencv-node\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Answer yourself and accept it if that's the answer. Don't leave the question like this.

Comment: i have the error above, can you help?

Comment: Try contacting the authors or create an issue on github.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the similar trouble.

The solution for me was to start "Developer Command Prompt for VS2015" as administrator(you need to install Visual Studio).
And ONLY in it I could install opencv (npm i opencv) without errors, but with warnings.

Maybe, it will help you too!